# EthAPI Internal LIB

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, goethe

I am not able to call the methods defined in
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi
from my GOLANG code.
Can anyone help me about this?

Regards
AKM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go you can't import an external package if the import path contains the word *internal* otherwise you get the error `use of internal package not allowed`. The *ethapi* is an internal package.

[source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)